# ATTENTION Matter Modelers: Can we ask 30 questions in the next 24 hours?

Tags: discussion, participation, site-promotion, other-se-sites

The following campaign has worked brilliantly over the last 2 weeks:

- [Matter Modeling needs a lot more questions before 28 July: Here's why](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/165/5)

Now we just need 30 more questions in the next 24 hours to meet the goal!

---

**You can help by:**

- ***[Asking a question](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)***!!! (if 30 of us ask just one question each, we're done!)

If you ***really*** don't want to ask a question (not even one that you can self-answer), then you can:

- Help by [encouraging these Physics.SE users to ask their age-old unanswered modeling questions here](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/171/5). **Leave comments so that they get pinged!**
- Help by [encouraging these Chem.SE users to ask their age-old unanswered modeling questions here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110113/whats-going-on-elsewhere). **Leave comments so that they get pinged!**
- ***Asking friends to ask at least one question!!!***

---

Many people have told me that they love this site, and that they feel this site is something that the community has needed for a very long time.

**But I fear too many people don't want to be involved in the dirty, boring, and energy-consuming *work* that a very small number of us have had to do in order for you to be able to enjoy having what we've built for you here.**

This includes:

- advertising,
- raising awareness to the 1000s of matter modelers on other SEs who aren't yet aware of us,
- **asking questions** (i.e. making contributions)
- 90% of our traffic comes from [HNQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109935/hot-network-questions-), so **ask more questions** and support our existing HNQ.

Your hard-work in helping keep this community ***strong***, is very much appreciated!

Comment: How many questions are left to ask to keep the site alive and how many more hours do we have?

Comment: 23 more questions in about 20 more hours :) I know you still have a lot of unanswered questions from Physics.SE that can be transferred here (even if you're no longer interested, others might find them useful)!

Comment: I will try to ask a few more questions in addition to the ones I have asked before. I believe this site should exist because there is nothing like it on the Stack Exchange and it is a community of help, where everyone has been friendly and helpful.

Comment: We have worked very hard on getting it approved by the Stack Exchange company: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122958/matter-modeling, and we are still trying our best to help it stay ***strong*** :)

Comment: Comments (on chemistry.se) have a tiny chance of surviving the first 24 hours if they just blatantly ask to move the question to mm; I can't remember how many I had already have to remove. They will be deleted with prejudice, if they could be conceived as suggesting the question is off topic on chemistry, when they are not k of while it isn't decided).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This is how our stats look as of now](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122958/matter-modeling).

We are doing **EXCELLENT** in terms of user base and are **OKAY** according to other metrics. However the most important metric Stack Exchange considers for site maturation is **questions per day**. We have a **24-hour window opportunity** to become excellent in this aspect also.

**We are so close and it will be a huge disappointment if we miss it by a small margin**.

## Let's ask some questions